# How to convert pdf to text in Flutter app web?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been looking for options to be able to read a PDF and convert it to TXT but so far I have not found any that have web support

What I have to do is have the user upload the pdf, once that is done a logic will be created to search for keywords and pre-fill a form, but I have not yet been able to go from pdf to txt

try pdf_text but it has no web support
syncfusion_flutter_pdf:
I had problems with this, I don't know if it is the creator's problem but it tells me that there is no library

Comment: Please share details on errors you are seeing with the syncfusion library, as well as anything else you've tried to accomplish this/

Comment: The problem with syncfusion_flutter is that my skd is version 3.2.3 and this does not support null security and if I change the sdk, other puvs do not work

Comment: Id suggested then looking for an older version of syncfusion that was not built for null saftey.